# Cesium OSM buildings floating in the air; could we set a custom ellipsoid, locally more accurate?

Tags: cesium, ellipsoid

I just discovered the way to include [OSM building](https://cesium.com/content/cesium-osm-buildings/) data in a [Cesium](https://cesium.com/) project. It sounds great but I also (re)-discovered my local ellipsoid vertical offset with the global [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) one (see pictures).

[image: UFO buildings]

*The "flying buildings syndrome" (they are certainly at the ground level referenced on the WGS84, but the local terrain tiles seem not, or I missed something).*

[image: Vertical offset Bessel-WGS84]
*We live 'on' the Bessel ellipsoid which is 50m lower than the WGS84.*

I may be wrong in my hypothesis, so let me know if it's the case.

Here is my question;

Did I miss something, e.g. to base the terrain tiles on the WGS84 ellipsoid?
If not, is there a way to fix this, for example by setting a different ellipsoid, more accurate locally than the global WGS84?
Or, any mean to bring the building back down to the ground?

Comment: Hi!, I'm facing somewhat the same issue-> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376270/cesium-terrain-generated-using-dsm-is-way-higher-than-the-base-map

Got any leads?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, that is add Cesium Terrian option, because Cesium OSM buildings are built for the Cesium Terrain.

Example: [image: Like this]

> Thank you for the information. I would start by ensuring that the
> terrain you generated is being added to the Cesium viewer correctly.
>
> Cesium OSM buildings are built for the Cesium Terrain. They are not
> designed to adapt to any terrain added to the Cesium viewer. Thus,
> seeing the Cesium OSM buildings floating in the air when added to a
> new terrain is not a bug.
>
> To populate your custom terrain with buildings, I suggest that you
> upload your desired building models to your Cesium ion account. Next,
> place the models in your terrain at specified coordinates. [This guide](https://cesium.com/learn/3d-tiling/ion-tile-set-location/)
> will help you set the location of data uploaded to Cesium ion:
>
> As always, more information helps me give you better assistance. Could
> you tell me a little bit more about your use case and desired
> functionality? Let me know if you have any questions or concerns!
>
> -Sam

[Reference](https://community.cesium.com/t/serving-custom-terrain-but-osm-buildings-is-floating-in-the-air/14391/2)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.