# Cesium Terrain generated using DSM is way higher than the base map

Tags: coordinate-system, 3d, elevation, cesium, quantized-mesh

Is there any way I can clamp the terrain to the base-map's height? Is the problem with the vertical datum for the data. I tried changing ellipsoid's radius-- but I learnt that the height is relative to the ellipsoid's base height.

I'm using `ctb-tiler` to generate the terrain. Playing around with `terrainExaggeration`-- usually setting it `0.1` brings it closer to the base layer, but I'm expecting that it would cause issues while measuring heights-- also it appears extremely flat [undesirable]

Is it due to TIFF being in different CRS, or vertical datum being off? Or is it something that I can correct using `cesium` options for viewer/terrain provider?

[image: Terrain]

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: Do you have a DEM/DSM file, use `ctb-tiler` to generate mesh, Use `cesium-terrain-server` to serve the generated terrain, try to visualize it on `cesium`. Let me know if more information is required.